# Как найти кол-во делителей последнего числа?

Tags: c++

Сама задачка(знаю, элементарно, но мне все равно сложно);

Пользователь вводит две цифры. Выведите все двухзначные числа, содержащие хотя бы одну из введенных
цифр. Выведите кол-во делителей последнего числа. Не использовать библиотеку cmath.

Comment: Вам просто код дать?

Comment: Да, но если будет объяснение кода, будет даже лучше

Comment: А Вы потом скажете, что этот код написали Вы? Так оно не работает.

Comment: Код я написал, но не до конца. В силу своих знаний, я дошел только до второго пункта, я не могу вывести кол-во делителей, не могли бы вы объяснить тогда или хотя бы намекнуть куда смотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x, y;
    
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            if (i == x or i == y or j == x or j == x){
                cout << i * 10 + j << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    int n = 90 + max(x, y);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В этот раз вы сами писали код, а не переделывали чужой. Так что про неэффективность поиска количества делителей (да и о том, что вы выводите делители, а не их количество) я промолчу только потому, что в условии было сказано о двузначном числе...

Answer (score 2):

1. Попробуйте в цикле каждое число от 10 до 99 переводить в строку и каждый символ сравнивать с каждой из введённых цифр (если они равны, то заносим в массив из 89 ячеек).
2. Ищем первую пустую ячейку массива, получаем число из ячейки с номером, меньшим на 1. (Получаем последнее число)
3. В цикле делим это число на числа от 1 до этого числа. Если остаток равен 0, то заносим это число в массив из 99 ячеек. (Получаем делители последнего числа)
4. Считаем количество заполненных ячеек второго массива. (Количество делителей последнего числа)

Comment: Спасибо! Но суть в том, что пользоваться я могу только циклом for, без массивов, чисто на циклах for.